# Problem of tcolorbox inside of beamer using XeLaTex

Tags: beamer, xetex, tcolorbox, xepersian

the following code works fine in article class but in beamer class it produce white space for persian text!

Compile details: XeLaTeX + TexLive 2022 + TeXstudio 4.5.1 + Windows 10

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%aspectratio = 169
%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{B Yas}
%\setdigitfont{Yas}
%\setfontfamily{\yas}{B Yas}
%\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\yas}
%\setmainfont{B Yas}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]{mytitle}
        \tcbset{enhanced,colback=red!5!white,
            boxrule=0.4pt,%sharp corners,
            colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\Huge,box align=center,
            halign=center,
            valign=center,coltext=green}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[drop lifted shadow]
            \Huge
            I think, therefore I am!\\
            مولوی یک شاعر متبحر است. Not printed!\\
            Why??
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't test because I don't have the fonts, but can you try to set the sans font, e.g. `\setsansfont{...}`?

Comment: That worked!! You can try using any font that you have. download it here https://www.fontyab.com/download?id=7044

Comment: Great to hear this is working!